APIM quota-by-key policy when condition JWT subject
I have an API which is currently secured using the validate-jwt policy.  The output token I get from a variable and want to give different quotas to different customers, for this I am using the "subject" of the JWT to identify.  This seems to work if I have quota-by-key in the inbound policy with no when condition and a counter key of the JWT subject (jwt-token being my output token from validate-jwt policy).  After 5 calls I get a 403 Quota Exceeded in my postman test:
<quota-by-key calls="5" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt-token"]).Subject)" />

If I then try to embed this in a when condition so based on the subject I want to give them different quotas I can't seem to get that to work.  I have tried for example:
<when condition="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt-token"]).Subject == "MYSUBJECTSTRING")">
                <quota-by-key calls="5" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt-token"]).Subject)" />
            </when>

and also the below as "Subject" is defined on MS as string (so using Equals):
<when condition="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt-token"]).Subject.Equals("MYSUBJECTSTRING"))">
                <quota-by-key calls="5" renewal-period="86400" counter-key="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt-token"]).Subject)" />
            </when>

None of these work and I can go way over the 5 calls.  This is all with the same token so Subject is the same...in fact the token was valid for 24 hours so the same token was used to do all this testing.
Anyone got any ideas or had any similar problems?
Lastly I know the "proper" solution is to use Products and apply the policies there but I only have a few customers and wanted to try this without having the overhead of setting up Products etc.
Thanks!

Use when condition in <choose></choose>.
I am able to get the expected response by using the given policy.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
        <set-variable name="jwt-token" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization").AsJwt())" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt-token"]).Subject == "{Subject}")">
                <quota-by-key calls="5" renewal-period="300" counter-key="@(((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt-token"]).Subject)" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
</policy>





Thanks Afrin.  I already have the when condition inside the  node, I just didnt add it in my description so apologies.  However, whereabouts are you seeing the log of quota-by-key policy running in 0.012 and 0.024?  Is this something in APIM, log analytics or app insights as this may be handy for me to look at my tests.  Thanks!

are you talking about sdk version? can you share the error message you are getting?

No I mean where are you seeing the screenshots you have pasted above showing quota-by-key was successfully evaluated?  Also, I am not getting any error message as my API just responds with 200 all the time as the quota-by-key policy is not getting invoked (which is why i would like to see the above information you shared...I just don't know how to access this)?

@Steve You need to make 5 calls one after another. You can access Trace here

@Steve make sure when condition executes to true

Thanks, how and where can I verify my when condition executes to true?

@Steve Check in Trace

Thank you for your help.  It seems to now be working and I am getting the correct 403 although don't think I really changed anything so ill have to go back over my fiddling around to see what was the issue....thanks again, much appreciated.
